# Spring caching eviction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I am having trouble with understanding spring @cacheEvict annotation. Does it a method to trigger cache eviction? Please see below.

```
  @CacheEvict
  public void clearEmployeeById(int id) {
      //Do we have to add a method as trigger here in order to trigger the cache eviction? or can we leave this method without implementation
           
  }
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the cache name in `@CacheEvict`

```
@CacheEvict(value = {"employee"}, allEntries = true)
public void clearEmployeeById(int id) {
      //Logic
}
```

Cache `employee` will get `evicted`, Whenever `clearEmplyoeeByID()` method gets invoked.

To add cache into `employee`

```
@Cacheable(value = {"employee"})
public Employee addEmployeeById(int id) {
   //Logic
   return employee;
}
```

To clear all cache, you need to use `CacheManager`

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 86400000)
public boolean evictAllCaches() {
    cacheManager.getCacheNames().stream().forEach(c -> cacheManager.getCache(c).clear()); 
    return true;
}
```